# bind same viewModel to different area but with different values Knockout Js

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I want to apply a bind of the same **ViewModel** to different modalbox that show same info but holds different values, i try to add an Id to the modals to apply the binding like this.

`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("firstModal"));`
`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("secondModal"));`

it binds ok, but when i change a value in any of the modals it changes in the other,

my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SgkbD/1/ with some kind of example of what i want to.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just do it like so http://jsfiddle.net/pmarshallandrew/SgkbD/19/
and use a different instance of the same viemodel?

...This works perfectly as you have  a different instance of the same viewmodel bound to two different parts of the DOM. 
Edit- Have updated with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, your example doesn't show what you are describing.

To answer your question, this is the expected behavior.  This is because you are binding the same observable object to two different locations.  But because it is the same observable, updating it in any way, then all the bindings that reference it will be updated.

I've updated your example to show this at http://jsfiddle.net/SgkbD/8/

---

**EDIT**
After your answer below, the obvious answer is you cannot. The same property That would go against the design of knockout.

However, you can do what I did in this http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/SgkbD/9/.  You can bind different properties of the view model in different sections.

If you want two different copies of the viewmodel, each bound to a different section, that also works.

Comment: Sorry, for the example i put the wrong link, i check your link is ok, but, i want not to change the observables of one section, i mean i want the same viewModel for the differents sections without duplicating it :/

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a single viewmodel object that when you update in one section, does not update in the other section?